# how to access a variable in a different activity? (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a button in an activity that when pressed adds 1 to a text view in another activity. However, when I try to access that variable in a different activity, I cannot. How could I solve this without passing intents (making the variable open for use in the whole program)?

Comment: If you want to do so, create an Activity with that variable and then use Fragments and from Fragment you access the stuff of your Activity, but it's not a good praxis though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use companion object in the Activity where you set the desired variable:

```
class ShowCaseActivity : Activity {

  companion object {
    var yourVariable = 0
  }
}
```

Now you can use this variable in every file in the project, you just have to import it accordingly like this:

```
import ShowCaseActivity.Companion.yourVariable

....

val number = ShowCaseActivity.yourVariable
```

It should be said that this is not a recommended way of solving this issue. You should pass data between Activities with intents.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wall between Activities and you can only pass data over that wall with Intents. For this reason, it is recommended to use only one Activity. You can use Fragments to represent your different screens. Use an Activity-scoped ViewModel to hold properties and LiveData you need to access from both screens.

In your case, you would have a function in the ViewModel that the button calls. The function would increment a private variable and set its value to a public LiveData. The TextView would observe that LiveData so it is automatically updated when the value is changed.